# True crypt - forgotten password

Tags: passwords, truecrypt, password-recovery, raspberry-pi

I've got a small true crypt container (that I created and own) I have forgotten the password too and would like access to.

Are there any tools available to crack true crypt containers? Bonus points for people who suggest tools that can work on a **Raspberry Pi**!

Thanks!

Comment: I most certainly hope not. It would render my usb portable *solution* useless.

Comment: It is possible to crack truecrypt containers, I want a raspberryPi solution or reccomendations though :P

Comment: Do you have some information on how to crack truecrypt containers *(sorry for answering my question instead of getting yours answered :) and not my downvote btw)*

Comment: The only tool I've found so far is [this](http://code.google.com/p/truecrack/).

Comment: That is what has been posted as an answer. It will fortunately not work with decent passwords.

Comment: I don't understand why the question has been down-voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No way except using `bash` or another scripting language to iterate through every possible password and attempt to mount it, i.e. "brute force."

Using a list of common or dictionary passwords may lower the amount of time, if you were prone to doing that.  I've never heard of @Todd Davies tool but it is worth looking at (seems GPU accelerated ...)

Comment: I don't think the GPU acceleration will work on my Raspberry Pi, but I've managed to obtain the files through the use of undelete software (I stored the files on my desktop temporarily). (Note: I only put the files in a true crypt container to protect them in my dropbox.)

Comment: @ToddDavies, you can recover the encrypted versions of the files, but not the plaintext...

Comment: No, I put them on my desktop, then transfered them into the container, then deleted them off my desktop. I undeleted the desktop files :)